# Centrally Align CSS Box Flip Animation UL

Tags: jquery, html, css, transform

I have got a CSS 3D transformation effect, which I would like to align to the center of the page.

Basically, I am using two divs; a front and a back in side a div, which then get transformed with CSS by adding a class on hover with jQuery.

So *I would like to align the whole block of boxes (eventually I'll have about five boxes) to the center.*
I have tried:

```
 ul, #subjectCardsContainer {
   display: block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

*And with 'ul' and '#subjectCardsContainer' on their own*

---

## My whole code

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jofish999/L86g5s9c/6/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".card").hover(function() {
      $(this).addClass("flip");
    });
    $(".card").mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("flip");
   });
 });
```

```css
ul, #subjectCardsContainer {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
 li {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
     margin: 0px 5px;
}
    .card {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      perspective: 800px;
    }
    .card div {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
      transition-duration: 400ms;
      z-index: 10;
    }
    .card .front {             /*  Front of each card  */
      background: red;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .card .back {              /*  Back of each card  */
      background: blue;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 0;
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    .card.flip .front {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); transform: rotateY(180deg);
      z-index: 0;  }
    .card.flip .back {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg); transform: rotateY(360deg);
      z-index: 10;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="subjectCardsContainer">
  <ul>
      <li>
          <div class="container">
              <div class="card">
                  <div class="front">
                      <p>Front 1</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="back">
                      <p>Back 1</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </li>
      <li>
          <div class="container">
              <div class="card">
                  <div class="front">
                      <p>Front 2</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="back">
                      <p>Back 2</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: @do you need both horizontally and vertically centered. ?? or if you just need horizontally centered you could use my answer..if you need both,then i will edit my answer

Comment: No thank you, just horizontal. @SajadKaruthedath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `text-align:center` for the container.

```
ul, #subjectCardsContainer {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align:center;  //added
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/L86g5s9c/8/)

Comment: Np. Just as an aside, `text-align` seems to work on its own witout the need of the `display` and `margins`

Comment: @Jofish: yes...but i just added text-align to it..i thought you may need it in mian site for other reponsive needs.. :)

Comment: @Jofish: is there any trouble ?